# Entity Framework with LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

What is difference between change / change2?

```
using (var context = new NORTHWNDEntities())
{
    var change = context.Regions.Where(r => r.RegionDescription == "East").ToList();

    var change2 = (from r in context.Regions where r.RegionDescription == "East" select new {r.RegionID, r.RegionDescription }).ToList();

    foreach (var p in change2)
    {
        p.RegionDescription = "West";
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I trying to make update on change2 in foreach loop i got error:

> Property or indexer '......' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

It works on previous version with lambda. How Can i change it to work?

Comment: Sounds like `RegionDescription` is a read only property... What about the error is confusing you?  It does not work in the lambda either since the lamda is checking equality (`==`), not performing assignment (`=`)

Comment: You also returned an anonymous type in the 2nd version. You need to return an actual object if you want to change the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var change2 = (from r in context.Regions 
                where r.RegionDescription == "East" 
                select new {r.RegionID, r.RegionDescription }).ToList();
```

You are returning an anonymous type. Anonymous type properties are read-only. If you want to change the value, you need to return an actual type that you have defined.

You can either `new` something else like `new Region` or just return `r`

```
var change2 = (from r in context.Regions 
                where r.RegionDescription == "East" 
                select r).ToList(); 


 var change2 = (from r in context.Regions 
                where r.RegionDescription == "East" 
                select new Region {.RegionID = r.RegionID, 
                                   .RegionDescription = r.RegionDescription }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and explanation, it works perfect! :)

Comment: @Danki Glad it worked out. Please mark Answered on one of the submissions.

Answer (score 1):

change2 returns an anonymous type which is immutable.
To amend the value, you need to write:

```
var change2 = (from r in context.Regions where r.RegionDescription == "East" select r).ToList();
```

Which is equivalent to change1.